# Is it a pun intended here in the lyrics?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When I surfed the internet to find such an interesting or funny lingistic problem, which I don't think I can have clear idea, so I'd draw your attention to it if you could give a hand.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do not see a pun here. The lyrics does not contain the meaning of "make love".

It just means when we loved each other, we were at that place.

Comment: But have you not read the words given in the original text? That love in Chinese is not an act, so it could not be attached to a place. It would be very ridiculous that you and I love each other in the wheat waves and that when we leave we do not love each other. That sounds more like paid sex, than love.

Comment: "In the wheat waves" is just an expression to describe a place (maybe their home town). It could be the symbolic thing for that place. It conveys that they had fallen in love with each other in a such beautiful place with "wheat waves", "blue sky"(at least from author's perspective, it's a beautiful place). Everything he put is just to try to be romantic I think.

Comment: @NanningYouth Lyrics do not always "make sense" in the normal way. I've read the message in your picture, and I've searched for the full lyrics. And I sense no sex in lyrics as native.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with fefe's answer. Additionally, it might also indicate that they shared some important memories there.

The writer used the word 浪 to describe the wheat field which could mean (a) the he/she has a lot of memories for them or misses his/her ex-lover a lot and (b) his/her love for that person was deep like the ocean.